# How do you delete/fix currupted folders in NTFS

Tags: ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have a corrupted folder on my external NTFS hard drive and it doesn't seem to let me delete it.

The output of `ls -la` (replacing my username with 'xxxx')

```
ls: cannot access 'hd/backgrounds': Input/output error
total 60
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users 16384 Oct 21 15:53  .
drwxr-xr-x 22 xxxx users  4096 Oct 21 15:53  ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users     0 Oct 13 18:43  .Trash-1001
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users  4096 Oct 16 10:59 'System Volume Information'
d?????????  ? ?        ?         ?            ?  backgrounds
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users  4096 Oct 14 12:31  backups
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users     0 Oct 11 15:56  documents
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users  8192 Mar 24  2020  drawing
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users     0 Mar 24  2020  games
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users  4096 Oct 10 22:10  iso
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users  4096 Mar 24  2020  modeling
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users  4096 Mar 24  2020  programming
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users 12288 Oct 10 21:14  unsorted
drwxrwxrwx  1 xxxx users     0 Oct 20 10:08  vids
```

of `rm -rf backgrounds`

```
rm: cannot remove 'hd/backgrounds': Input/output error
```

of `sudo ntfsfix --clear-dirty --clear-bad-sectors /dev/sdb3`

```
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
Going to un-mark the bad clusters ($BadClus)... No bad clusters...OK
NTFS partition /dev/sdb3 was processed successfully.
```

I can't find anything about how to fix this past ntfsfix so I'm stuck. Anyone know anything about how to solve this?

EDIT:
The output of a SMART test

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                ( 7216) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 121) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   142   142   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       68
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   127   127   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       181 (Average 180)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       5644
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   110   110   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       36
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       13103
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       5317
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       5651
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       5651
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       30 (Min/Max 13/42)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1376         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Have you verified drive health with SMART?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with SMART but I've put an output of it in the question if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`ntfsfix` is a very rudimentary utility which doesn't always fix NTFS errors.

You have two options:

- Reformat and restore from backups
- Use the `chkdsk.exe` utility from Windows. If you don't have a Windows license, Microsoft allows you to download and use [Windows 10 Enterprise](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise) for 180 days. You can install it on a bare metal or in a VM.